# IllegalArgumentException related to cron expression

Tags: cron, scheduler

While using the `cron` expression `0 42 5 31 DEC 2`, I received this error:

```
o.s.c.s.i.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter - Uncaught exception thrown
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Overflow in day for 
expression "0 42 5 31 DEC 2"
```

I need to understand why am I getting this error although this is a valid `cron` expression

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many expressions, `cron` allows 5 expressions: `minute, hour, day(of month),month, day(of week)`

So i'm assuming you want to write: `42 5 31 DEC 2`? either way you need to trim your expression from the left to match due to `DEC` being in the "right" spot.

experiment more [here](https://crontab.guru/#42_5_31_DEC_2).

Comment: the java doc mentions that 0 15 10 ? * MON-FRI is a valid expression. I triggered a task using this expression and that task got successfully executed so, i guess the expression is correct. Here is the document for reference - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm

Comment: Sorry this seems to be a version of cron that's different than the standard one and i'm unfamiliar with.